# Set timeout for get request with HTTP.jl

Tags: request, julia, connection-timeout

I got to scan IP ranges and want to reduce waiting time on the timeouts.
How do i specify the request timeout, with Julia's HTTP.jl package?

I have found the `readtimeout` option in the docs for [v.0.6.15](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/v0.6/):

```
conf = (readtimeout = 10,
        pipeline_limit = 4,
        retry = false,
        redirect = false)

HTTP.get("http://httpbin.org/ip"; conf..)
```

But in the current stable version [v0.8.6](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/public_interface/#Requests-1) `readtimeout` seams to only appear on the server side.

Testcode with `readtimeout=2` and v.0.8.6:

```
@time begin
    try
        HTTP.get("http://2.160.0.0:80/"; readtimeout=2)
    catch e
        @info e
    end
end
```

Output:

```
113.642150 seconds (6.69 k allocations: 141.328 KiB)
┌ Info: IOError(Base.IOError("connect: connection timed out (ETIMEDOUT)", -4039) during request(http://2.160.0.0:80/))
└ @ Main In[28]:5
```

So the request took about 114 seconds, hence i think that this option is currently unsupported.

**Edit**
I checked the source code ([HTTP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/master/src/HTTP.jl)) of the stable release:

```
Timeout options
 - `readtimeout = 60`, close the connection if no data is received for this many
   seconds. Use `readtimeout = 0` to disable.
```

with this example given:

```
HTTP.request("GET", "http://httpbin.org/ip"; retries=4, cookies=true)
HTTP.get("http://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"; aws_authorization=true)
conf = (readtimeout = 10,
        pipeline_limit = 4,
        retry = false,
        redirect = false)
HTTP.get("http://httpbin.org/ip"; conf..)
HTTP.put("http://httpbin.org/put", [], "Hello"; conf..)
```

So it should be working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely does not do what is expected.
There are multiple things going on here:

First off the default for idempotent requests in HTTP.jl is to retry 4 times. So a `HTTP.get` will only fail after `5 * readtimeout`. You can change this by passing `retry = false` in the arguments.

Second thing I noticed is that the check for timed out connections is on a very long interval. (See [TimeoutRequest Layer](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/master/src/TimeoutRequest.jl#L26)) It only checks every 8 to 12 seconds for a time out, so a timeout below 8 seconds is not doing anything. (I suspect these should be 8-12 milliseconds not seconds as implemented)

And finally the docs for 0.8.6 are missing for HTTP.request. I already [made a PR](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/pull/446) to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, good points i will try!
Yeah, i looked up the documentation in the source code now.

Comment: You seem to be right in both cases. Adding `retry=false` reduced the time to ~23 seconds. Now i'll have a look at the TimeaoutRequest_Layer.